# settings namespace in Django

Tags: python, django, coding-style, django-apps

I'm writing reusable Django app. What are best practices for adding own settings into `settings.py` ? Do I need to prefix every setting with my app_name, or maybe I should make only one setting dict. for my app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try to define app settings only in the package involved, especially if you are considering a reusable package. Sticking with unique global names (which settings are infact) is always a good idea. Have a look at [PEP-8 globals](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id31).

If you're creating a reusable package its good practice to first try to import the attribute from the settings module to see if the user is overriding it with its own constant.

E.g.

```
from django.conf import settings

MY_CONSTANT = getattr(settings, 'MY_CONSTANT', True)

def foo(*args, **kwargs):
    if MY_CONSTANT:
        return 'hello'
    else:
        return 'goodbye'
```

This way the user could set `MY_CONSTANT = False` in his settings module so the app will return `'goodbye'` instead of the default `'hello'`

Most packages do use the package name as a prefix as you suggested, here's a few examples:

[FEINCMS](https://github.com/feincms/feincms/blob/master/feincms/default_settings.py), [tastypie](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/models.py#L53)